# Why it doesnt get information from entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to get input from entry to the marks variable. Hopefully i will get some help there. I asked my teacher but he said that he doesn`t know how can i fix it.

It gives me such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "window1.py", line 46, in GButton_109_command
    marks = Line1.get()
            ^^^^^
NameError: name 'Line1' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```py
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("Підрахунок тематичної оцінки")
        # setting window size
        width = 300
        height = 200
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        Line1 = tk.Entry(root)
        Line1["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times', size=10)
        Line1["font"] = ft
        Line1["fg"] = "#333333"
        Line1["justify"] = "center"
        Line1["text"] = "Введіть оцінки через пробіл: "
        Line1.place(x=10, y=70, width=276, height=30)

        GLabel_323 = tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times', size=10)
        GLabel_323["font"] = ft
        GLabel_323["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_323["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_323["text"] = "Підрахунок тематичної оцінки"
        GLabel_323.place(x=10, y=20, width=278, height=30)

        GButton_109 = tk.Button(root)
        GButton_109["bg"] = "#f0f0f0"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times', size=10)
        GButton_109["font"] = ft
        GButton_109["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_109["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_109["text"] = "Submit"
        GButton_109.place(x=110, y=140, width=81, height=30)
        GButton_109["command"] = self.GButton_109_command

    def GButton_109_command(self):
        marks = Line1.get()
        mlist = marks.split()
        # convert each item to int type
        for i in range(len(mlist)):
            mlist[i] = int(mlist[i])

        ar = sum(mlist) / len(mlist)

        print(ar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you need some additional information, ask for it

Comment: _I asked my teacher but he said that he doesn`t know how can i fix it._ - well, it's really hard to buy this

Comment: Python is telling you everything that you need to know. In the function `GButton_109_command`, python can't find a variable named `Line1`. When defining `Line1 = ...`, use `self.Line1 = ...` instead. Same goes for every other occurrence of `Line1`

Comment: Please include the code within the body of your question. It was here previously, and you removed it for some reason.

Comment: Add to all line1 to `self.Line1`

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out, `Line1` is not in scope in the GButton_109_command method. Compare:

```py
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        Line1 = tk.Entry(root)
        # etc ...

    def GButton_109_command(self):
        marks = Line1.get()
        # etc...
```

with

```py
def first():
    x = "this"

def second():
    x += " and also that"
```

In both code snippets, the variable is defined only within the function that defines it. The usual way to do what you want to do here is to save `Line1` as a field of this instance of `App`, as in:

```py
class App
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.line_1 = tk.Entry(root)  # I also fixed casing, since Python
                                      # prefers snake_case idiomatically
        # etc...

    def gbutton_109_command(self):
        marks = self.line_1.get()
        # etc...
```

Here we're modifying the `self` object to contain (and *persist*) the `tk.Entry` object. Your method then can refer to the `tk.Entry` later on because it's handed the same object reference as `self`.